# Replace the Nth occurrence of a character on each line in VIM

Tags: vim, replace

I have the following data and I want to replace the 3th occurrence of the | symbol with nothing.

```
ABC | DEF | GHI | XYZ | 123
ABC | DEF | GHI | XYZ | 123
ABC | DEF | GHI | XYZ | 123
```

Final output should be:

```
ABC | DEF | GHI  XYZ | 123
ABC | DEF | GHI  XYZ | 123
ABC | DEF | GHI  XYZ | 123
```

Comment: There is a vim stackexchange site: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to https://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following:

`:%norm 3f|r`

This means:

- `:%norm` on every line, run the following normal commands
- `3f|` move cursor to the 3rd occurrence of `|`
- `r`  replace it with a space

You could of course do:

`:%norm 3f|x`

To delete the `|` completely.

Another way would be to use visual block mode (see `:help visual-block`).
Although this will only work if all the `|` are lined up (i.e. in the same
column).